# how to adjust images in every where i want to layout in android?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have an layout with a background that already made for host my app's image buttons. my image buttons are in a row of middle in this layout. my emulator is 480*800 px hdpi that dp is:320*533.
when i adjust buttons from xml, everything is OK. but when run, my buttons change smaller than from size of in xml and layout is not ordered. please help me. what can i do?

myt xml code for this layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


 android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_panel"
    >

</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="75dp">
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/help_ic"
    android:src="@drawable/help_main_hdpi"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feed_ic"
        android:src="@drawable/feed_main_hdpi"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_ic"
        android:src="@drawable/search_main_hdpi"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/read_ic"
        android:src="@drawable/read_main_hdpi"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you should provide some code and images

Comment: @PhanVănLinh xml code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have given weight to your ImageView,set

android:layout_width="0dp"

instead of "wrap_content" for the ImageView and give the total weightsum to the parent LinearLayout i.e 4 in your case. 
Try this, I hope It will help you.